# Protractor e2e | Element not clickable at point error | Angular Hybrid app

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular6

I have migrated our Angular JS app to Hybrid app. I am using Angular6/AngularJS (1.6) hybrid app. I am trying to run protractor e2e of the existing e2e tests for angular js pages. All test case are failing with the below reason.

```
button is not clickable at point (386, 20)

I am using Angular-Cli project. If I am trying to run this test individually they are passing. They fail when I am running in multiple tests together in a suite.

My protractor version : protractor": "^5.3.2
"webdriver-manager": "12.0.6",
"selenium-webdriver": "4.0.0-alpha.1",

I also tried with different version of protractor and selenium, but still got the same problem. I also tried applying the fixes below. That is also not working.
1)
var elem = element(by.id('yourId'));
browser.actions().mouseMove(elem).click();
2)
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

Failed: unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (386, 20). Other element would receive the click: ...
(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
at Object.checkLegacyResponse (\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
at parseHttpResponse (\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
at doSend.then.response (\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)

Node Version: `8.11.3
Protractor Version: 5.3.2
Angular Version: 6.0.4
AngularJS Version: 1.6.4
Browser(s): Chrome, firefix
Operating System and Version Windows 10
Your protractor configuration file
A relevant example test
Output from running the test
Steps to reproduce the bug
The URL you are running your tests against (if relevant)
Thanks,
Abhishek
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one thing you could do was to do clicking by `javascript`. This could be achieved using following function:

```
async function sendClick(element: ElementFinder): Promise<boolean> {
  try { 
    await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', await element.getWebElement());
    return true;
  }
  catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

#### Note

When clicking via `javascript` the `click` event is sent directly to the element and is not really simulated as a user would click it. So if the element is present on the page but not visible for example, it would still receive the click!

When using `element.click()` the element is scrolled into view and only clicked if it's clickable by mouse. So when using my provided technique, error's like these won't be found.

For having a reliable click function for clicking you'll have to add proper checks on your own. That could look as follows:

```
async function sendClick(element: ElementFinder): Promise<boolean> {
      try { 
        if(!await element.isDisplayed()) {
          return false;
        }
        await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', await element.getWebElement());
        return true;
      }
      catch (err) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: My e2e tests are running too fast since I moved them to latest Protractor version with Angular Hybrid app. Also I set the browser.ignoreSynchronization = true in my protractor.conf file.

Comment: Fix suggested by you worked. Thanks a lot Silvan Bregy !

Comment: Hi Silvan, This code resolve the click issue on one of the element, but for next element its not working. e.g. in my page I am clicking a pop-up page (which works fine with this code), then I am clicking on a radio button, using the same method, but here it waits for a long time, after then my test case with timeout error. Please advise.

Comment: I am using protractor for a few months now and clicking other elements than buttons is always very painful. It appears that in different cases different solutions for clicking work resp. do not work. I usually use `sendClick()` for clicking. If that does not work I try `element.click()` and if that also doesn't work I just use `browser.actions().mouseMove(element).click().perform()`.
I NEVER had a use case where neither of the 3 methods for clicking do work.